# What is the system color of a NSTextField's text?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield, nscolor

I manipulate the text color of a `NSTextField`. Due to the fact that these cells could be reused, I have to reset the color to the default one in my `tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)`-Method.

How do I get via Swift source the default text color of a `NSTextField`-control?

I know that is should be black but I don't wanna 'guess' the color to be update, user interaction safe.

I looked for a `NSTextField.defaultColor` property or an `NSColor.defaultTextFieldColor()` but I did not find any helpful solutions. I also could not find anything related in the official Apple class reference.

Comment: let tf = NSTextField(); let defaultTextColor = tf.textColor   Use this value as default later in your code.  Because .textColor is an optional  NSColor? you can set it to nil (I guess, Cocoa will use the default one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targeting 10.10 or later, then use `NSColor.labelColor()`. If you're targeting earlier versions of the OS, then use `NSColor.controlTextColor()`.